# Schedule a cronjob everytime it is done

Tags: linux-mint, cron, cronjob

I have a cronjon which runs every 48 hours. But ideally what I want is that it must start running as soon as it stops. Can this be done? It is an sh script consisting of a python command.
I am using Linux Mint 13.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds to me that this is something the shell script—or better yet, the Python script itself—should control, not cron. What command are you running? Please consider posting the shell script and Python command here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is run the python command in an infinite loop, and then run the script once using cron. That way the script will be run again each time it finishes:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do  ## Enter infinite loop
   sleep 5;   ## Wait for 5 seconds
   python -c 'print("hello world")'  ## Run your python command
done
```

If you save that script as, for example, `~/run_python.sh` and make it executable (`chmod +x ~/run_python.sh`), you can set it to run once on system boot using the `@reboot` prefix. Add this line to your crontab:

```
@reboot ~/run_python.sh
```

So, the BASH script will start on system boot and it will wait 5 seconds, run the python command and then keep doing so indefinitely.

A better, or at least more *nixy, way of doing this would be to add script to `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: I will run this on Amazon EC2 so reboot wont be required.